# Can the elements of a direct sum be thought of like that?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I've asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555486/how-to-really-understand-the-tensor-algebra) about the tensor algebra, and I think that my problem is being able to realise the elements of a direct sum as linear combinations. Indeed the rigorous definition I have of the direct sum of a family of vector spaces $\mathcal{F}_\Lambda = \{V_\lambda : \lambda \in \Lambda\}$ is:

$$\bigoplus_{\lambda \in \Lambda}V_\lambda=\{f : \Lambda \to\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} V_\lambda : f(\lambda)\in V_\lambda, f(\lambda)=0 \ \text{for all but finitely many} \ \lambda \in \Lambda\}$$

this is the set of all "sequences" $(v_\lambda)$ with $v_\lambda \in V_\lambda$. That's fine, but I see many people realise such a sequence $(v_\lambda)$ as a linear combination of elements of each $V_\lambda$.

The only way I could think to understand this began in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555518/basis-for-direct-sum-of-vector-spaces) where I concluded that if $i_\lambda : V_\lambda \to \bigoplus_{\lambda\in \Lambda}V_\lambda$ is given by $(i_\lambda(v))_{\mu}=v$ if $\lambda=\mu$ and zero otherwise, then if $\beta_\lambda$ is basis of $V_\lambda$ we have $\beta = \bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}i_\lambda(\beta_\lambda)$ basis of the direct sum. In that case, each element of the direct sum is a linear combination of those elements.

Then I thought on the following: if $e^{(\lambda)}_{k_\lambda}$ is a basis element of $V_\lambda$, then $i_\lambda(e^{(\lambda)}_{k_\lambda})$ is a basis element of the direct sum. More than that, this sequence represents $e^{(\lambda)}_{k_\lambda}$ inside the direct sum, so we simply denote it by $e^{(\lambda)}_{k_\lambda}$. In that case, the elements of the direct sum will be really linear combinations of elements of each $V_\lambda$. Is this correct? Is it usual to set this notation?

As an example, in the case of the tensor algebra $T(V)$, if $\{e_i\}$ is a basis of $V$, we would have for instance $e_1\otimes e_2$ element of the basis of $T^2_0(V)$ and $e_1\otimes e_2\otimes e_1$ element of the basis of $T^3_0(V)$. In that case, we could represent the element of $T(V)$

$$T=(2e_1+e_2, e_1\otimes e_2, 4e_1\otimes e_2\otimes e_1,0,\cdots) = 2e_1+e_2+e_1\otimes e_2+4e_1\otimes e_2\otimes e_3,$$

simply by identifying $(e_1,0,\dots)$ with $e_1$, $(0,e_1\otimes e_2,\dots,0,\dots)$ with $e_1\otimes e_2$ and so on.

Is this way to think and work with direct sums usual? I'm unsure, mainly about denoting $i_\lambda(e^{(\lambda)}_{k_\lambda})$ by simply $e^{(\lambda)}_{k_\lambda}$.

For me it seems there are problems, because if we had $\mathbb{R}^2\oplus\mathbb{R}^2$, then $e_1$ would stand both for $(e_1,0)$ and $(0,e_1)$. So how people really consider the direct sum as the space of linear combinations of the elements of the spaces involved?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you've written is correct. As for what to do notationally with the basis of $\mathbb{R}^2\oplus \mathbb{R}^2$, you can easily solve your quandary by labeling the basis vectors as $\{e_1^{(1)}, e_2^{(1)}, e_1^{(2)}, e_2^{(2)}\}$, corresponding to the two maps $i_1, i_2:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2\oplus \mathbb{R}^2$ with $i_1(v) = (v, 0)$ and $i_2(v) = (0, v)$.